# Is there a generic way to deserialize single-valued value objects (without custom Deserializer) in Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, kotlin, jackson, deserialization

We use a lot of value objects with a single value. For (de-)serialization we use Jackson with the kotlin-module.

A example value object in Kotlin:

```
data class MyValueObject(val value: String)
```

or as Java

```
class MyValueObject {
 private String value;

 public MyValueObject(String value) { this.value = value; }

 public String getValue() { return value; }
}
```

These value objects have to be serialized **and deserialized** and should be serialized "value only", eg. `"theValue"` instead of `"{"value":"theValue"}"`.

I would like to avoid writing custom serializers/deserializers for dozens of value objects.

I know for serialisation `@JsonValue` can be used to realize the above.

```
data class MyValueObject(@JsonValue val value: String)
```

But the JSON ""theValue"" (the above serialized String-Literal) cannot be deserialized back as `MyValueObject`. It sesults in the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: 
Cannot construct instance of `[...].MyValueObject` (although at least one Creator exists): 
no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('test')
 at [Source: (String)""test""; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Here is the Unit Test I used:

```
@Test
fun testSerialize() {
    val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(Jdk8Module())
        .registerModule(KotlinModule())
    val test = MyValueObject("test")
    val json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(test)
    println(json)
    objectMapper.readValue<MyValueObject>(json)
}
```

Is there a simple/generic way to deserialize these like `@JsonValue` for serializing?

P.S.: One working solution (thanks to @LppEdd) is:

```
data class MyValueObject (@JsonValue val value: String) {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @JsonCreator
        fun create(value: String) = MyValueObject(value)
    }
}
```

But this is very verbose. @JsonCreator annotated on the constructor did not work for me (see my comment on the answer of @LppEdd)

Comment: So "theValue" is a simple string?

Comment: Yes, it is a String.

Comment: @MarcvonRenteln see answer. JsonCreator works for every primitive type too (string and numbers).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure, and it's pretty simple.
Just add `@JsonCreator` to the constructor.

```
class MyValueObject {
  private String value;

  @JsonCreator
  public MyValueObject(String value) { this.value = value; }

  @JsonValue
  public String getValue() { return value; }
}
```

Or for Kotlin you'd have, I suppose

```
data class MyValueObject @JsonCreator constructor(@JsonValue val value: String)
```

---

When you use `@JsonCreator` **without** prefixing the constructor parameter with

```
@JsonProperty("fieldName")
```

you tell Jackson to pass the entire JSON string, which in your case is just a "primitive" value.

---

Apparently Kotlin doesn't like auto-generated getter/setters pairs.
This works for example

```
class MyValueObject @JsonCreator constructor(private val value: String) {
    @JsonValue
    fun getValue() = value
}
```

Also, after a bit of debugging, I found out the problem arises here

```
@Override
public Boolean hasAsValue(Annotated a) {
    JsonValue ann = _findAnnotation(a, JsonValue.class);
    if (ann == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return ann.value();
}
```

At `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`.

I don't know why but Jackson still look for a `@JsonValue` annotation on a **public** field or on a **public** getter. Kotlin places the annotation on the **private** field, so Jackson cannot find it.

The solution is

```
data class MyValueObject @JsonCreator constructor(@JvmField @JsonValue val value: String)
```

or even better

```
data class MyValueObject @JsonCreator constructor(@get:JsonValue val value: String)
```

---

As Marc von Renteln wrote in the comments, you can also omit `@JsonCreator`

```
data class MyValueObject(@get:JsonValue val value: String)
```

Which seems undocumented, however. If someone can point out where this behavior is described, it would be awesome!

Comment: Sorry, @JsonCreator did not work for me. When I deserialize `class MyValueObject @JsonCreator constructor(@JsonValue val value: String)` it results in the same exception (I added it to the description). I've added my test method to the question. When I decompile the kotlin dataclass to Java the constructor looks like this: ```@JsonCreator
   public MyValueObject(@NotNull String value) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(value, "value");
      super();
      this.value = value;
   }``` This seems right. But jackson does not use it.

Comment: @MarcvonRenteln strange. I've tested what I posted. Let me try.

Comment: @MarcvonRenteln okay, it's a Kotlin problem. I'll see what i can do

Comment: I have added a working solution with a companion method. But this is to verbose. So @JsonCreator works with static methods but not with Kotlin-Constructors...?

Comment: @MarcvonRenteln I came up with a similar solution. I'm trying to understand why constructors don't work.

Comment: @MarcvonRenteln can't you use a Java class in place of a Kotlin one? Just a possibility.

Comment: We have a kotlin project. This would cause dozens of Java classes and two compilers. For Java classes I would have to add equals/hashCode/toString/Constructor so the above "verbose" solution in Kotlin would be much smaller. So, no, I would not use Java classes instead.

Comment: @MarcvonRenteln Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191166/discussion-between-lppedd-and-marc-von-renteln).

Comment: @MarcvonRenteln look at the bottom. Solution found ;)

Comment: @MarcvonRenteln found another solution, which seems the perfect one. At the bottom.

Comment: The chat link didn't work for me in firefox and chrome. :( I analyzed the bytecode, reworked your first idea and in the meantime I found the exact same solution as your last suggestion with `@get:` ;) Great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is an even shorter version. The problem was the missing `get:` and not the `@JsonCreator constructor(...)`. You can drop it and it works: `data class MyValueObject(@get:JsonValue val value: String)`. I have tested this with String, UUID, LocalDate and in conjunction with an outer class. It works without `@JsonCreator`.

Comment: @MarcvonRenteln just verified, works in Java too. Thanks! I think using JsonCreator does help to notice what Jackson will do, however (for the developer who read the code).

Comment: Would you add it to your answer?

Comment: @MarcvonRenteln done! It's interesting. I don't think it is documented, I'll take a look

Comment: The documentation for `JsonCreator` states "*One common use case is to use a delegating Creator to construct instances from scalar values (like java.lang.String) during deserialization, and serialize values using JsonValue.*" That's why I say it's strange.

Comment: Normally a skip this part, but this time I have to say it: thank you @LppEdd

Comment: To be more explizit it might be good practice to explicitly set @JsonCreator(mode = Mode.DELEGATING). Just in case someone suddenly wanted to add another argument for some reason, or the DEFAULT mode was changed by Jackson.