# Kotlin Jackson - How to process (deserialize) nested JSON?

Tags: spring, kotlin, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize nested JSON into a single DTO in a Spring Boot application. The JSON:

```
{
   "values":[
      {
         "name":"test",
         "map":{
            "d1":"d1Value",
            "d2":"d2Value",
            "d3":"d3Value"
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"test1",
         "map":{
            "d1":"d1Value",
            "d4":"d4Value"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

My kotlin classes:

```
    data class A(
        val values: List<B>,
    )

    data class B(
        val name: C,
        val map: Map<D, String>,
    )

    data class C(@JsonValue val value: String)
    data class D(@JsonValue val value: String)
```

When I try deserialize json using jacksonObjectMapper`mapper.readValue<A>(jsonObject)` I receive error:

```
Cannot construct instance of `...C` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('test')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem, the solution:

```
data class C(@get:JsonValue val value: String)
data class D(@get:JsonValue val value: String)
```

based on: [Is there a generic way to deserialize single-valued value objects (without custom Deserializer) in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492657/is-there-a-generic-way-to-deserialize-single-valued-value-objects-without-custo)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `C` and `D` are always `String`, simply use `String` in the model as follows:

```kotlin
data class A(
    val values: List<B>,
)

data class B(
    val name: String,
    val map: Map<String, String>,
)
```